# Вычеслить имя папки, подправить код

Tags: php

Вот есть такая функция

```
public function get_upload_dir($id) {
    for($i=2;$i>=1;$i--) {
        $dir_file_arr[]=ceil($id/pow(1000,$i));
    }
        $dir_file_str=implode("/", $dir_file_arr);
    return $dir_file_str;
}
```

суть в том что я передаю функции id  а она мне должна вернуть путь к папке

в цикле число 2 - это количество ветвей папок

максимально возможное значение $id равно 1000 в 3-й степени, т.е. 1000 000 000 (степень - количество ветвей+1)

разберем функцию на простом примере, вот таком

```
public function get_upload_dir($id) {
    for($i=2;$i>=1;$i--) {
        $dir_file_arr[]=ceil($id/pow(3,$i));
    }
        $dir_file_str=implode("/", $dir_file_arr);
    return $dir_file_str;
}
```

максимальное значение тут 27

т.е. вот что должен я получить

id=1 ответ 1/1

id=2 ответ 1/1

id=3 ответ 1/1

id=4 ответ 1/2

id=5 ответ 1/2

id=11 ответ 2/4

id=25 ответ 3/9

как исправить функцию так, что бы получить нумерацию вот в таком виде?

id=1 ответ 1/1

id=2 ответ 1/1

id=3 ответ 1/1

id=4 ответ 1/2

id=5 ответ 1/2

id=11 ответ 2/1

id=25 ответ 3/3

т.к. есть 3 папки 1, 2, 3

в этих папких в кажой так же есть 1, 2, 3

а сейчас функция делает так

есть 3 папки 1, 2, 3

в каждой есть 3 папки имена которых порядковый номер вычесленный по формуле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача как-то сумбурно описана, но если я правильно понял, что у вас в итоге должно получаться, то решение примерно [такое](http://ideone.com/2MqXw9):

```
function get_upload_dir($id) {
    $p = 3;
    for ($i = 2; $i >= 1; $i--) {
        $dir = ceil($id / pow($p, $i)) % $p;
        $dir_file_arr[] = $dir > 0 ? $dir : $p;
    }
    $dir_file_str = implode("/", $dir_file_arr);
    return $dir_file_str;
}
```

Надеюсь, назначение `$p` вам понятно :-)

И совет: не жалейте разделителей. Вам потом легче будет свой же код разбирать.

Вообще рекомендую придерживаться какого-либо codestyle. Примеры: [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/coding-standard.html), [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/ru/standards.php).

Comment: спасибо огромное, сам код вот

http://hashcode.ru/questions/254787/php-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE_%D0%BE

Comment: А ссылка на код зачем?

Теперь не понятно, мой ответ решил вашу задачу или нет?

Comment: Да, решил, огромное Вам спасибо!

вы написали "Задача как-то сумбурно описана" вот я ссылку и написал